# How to Handle WCF Client Disconnect

Tags: c#, wcf

How can I handle WCF Client Disconnects ?

I Tried CallBacks but it seems to only works when Client Disconnect "clearly" by using a "Disconnect" button for example.

I want my server to be notified when Client got disconnected, even on manual disconnect or client process crash.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to reconnect on a timeout or have a manual connect/disconnect?

Comment: I want my server to be notified when Client got disconnected, even on manual disconnect or client process crash

Answer (score 7):

Use the OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted and OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed events.

These events are fired when the client has disconnected for whatever reason.

Comment: The OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed event doesn't fire for me at anytime... 

I want an event to fire when i quit the client WinForm... I'm using wsDualHttpBinding in WCF.

How do you use this event ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a loop where the client just pings the service every second or so and then do a callback. when the callback fails then the client has disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on polling would be to use messaging.  The client could post an "I'm here" message and then delete the message when it disconnects.  The server could monitor the queue for disconnects.  Another option is to use [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html), bi-directional HTTP communication.  This is what web chat clients use.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if the client disconnects in a abnormal way there´s no way to make sure that the server will be aware of that. It´s pretty much like HTTP. If we close the browser, let´s say with a force quit, the browser won´t send anything to the server.

That´s one of many reasons why we have session timeout. To disconnect a client and clean up in the server side everything that is being used if a client do something wrong (too long operations for example) or disconnects without letting the server know.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected == false)
{
..}
```

it can help you