# WCF service, users login - how to handle if they are disconnected prematurely?

Tags: c#, wcf, p2p

I am creating a p2p application. I will host a webservice at some url that users will use to log in to the system and find each other's ip addresses. I am using WCF for the web service. Part of the application will let users chat peer to peer.

So I presume when users log in I just update an 'Online' column in the Users database table to true. And when they log off I set this to false. But what happens if the connection is closed another way, such as if they lose internet connectivity, then they won't get a chance to call the 'log off' function...How is this situation handled with WCF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Handle WCF Client Disconnect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665473/how-to-handle-wcf-client-disconnect)