# C# WCF MySQL track concurrent users

Tags: c#, wcf

What is a good way to track connected users to my WCF server.  EX:  I have user accounts that each have usage sessions.  If a user has 100 sessions registered on his account, he can connect 100 times from the same username.  Keeping track of connections is straight-forward. But what about how to keep track if a user disconnects?  How can the server be notified that the TCP connection on the end user got terminated?

I am creating a handler for when the channel gets closed.  But how can I now match something in the sender / EventArgs to meaningful connection data.

```
    OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += _Closed;
    private void _Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Different context, but this sound like a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338842/detect-socket-disconnect-in-wcf or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665473/how-to-handle-wcf-client-disconnect

Comment: Don't understand the question of How can you match something to "meaningful connection data"?  What is the data your looking to collect?

Answer (score 0):

you can save your connection channels in dictionary when connection created and remove it on this event. therefore you can track concurrent users ;)